# Woolentor Products Add to Cart showing weird border

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

[Image showing problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBQGN.png)

Please see the image, around the add to basket button text there is a weird border, I am using elementor and WL product,

I could find nothing within the elementor settings to affect this border. I have no idea where this border is coming from.

Comment: Use the developer tools to inspect the element and see what is adding the border or just apply css rule to remove it. Without giving url to the website we cant tell for sure 100% how to fix this.

Comment: Yes I have trid to do this with additional css, but cant seem to change it. Here's the link to website - diamondrooms.co.uk

Comment: I cant reproduce this problem could be just render issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved now, it was some global colours from my theme that was interfering.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).